# CREATE/ALTER INDEX permission

Tags: sql-server, permissions

How can I grant a user create/alter index permissions without giving db_ddladmin? I want them to have the minimum permissions possible.

Answer (score 2):

The minimum `permission` to `create`/`alter` index can be easily found in corresponding BOL articles [CREATE INDEX (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions) and [ALTER INDEX (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions):

> Requires ALTER permission on the table or view.

This means you can grant `alter table` on every `table` of interest that already exists.

If you don't want to grant so granular `permissions` you can grant `alter on schema(s)` where your table(s) reside, this will assure that the user would be able to `create`/`alter` indexes on any future `table`/`view`.